# Read spinner input

Tags: java, swing, input, spinner, jspinner

In order to get the amount of players (required for a game), I implemented a spinner (from 2 to 8).
In order to start the game, I need to get the selected item. I made some research and added the following code:

```
int numPlayers = (int) spinner.getValue();
```

But this solely returns the minimum spinner number, instead of returning the number selected by the user. Is there any other way to get the selected spinner number?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 1):

The key is **when** you call this code. For this to work, it must be part of a listener, possibly a ChangeListener, that has been added to your JSpinner.

Comment: More specifically, it's best that the value is retrieved while in the event dispatch thread. That's normally done by running the code from a Listener. Where I disagree is that the listener should likely be on another control, for example a "start" button's ActionListener. You can retrieve the value there, and you only need to retrieve it once. But this is likely the crux of the problem.